# An error has occured. Please see log file - eclipse

Tags: eclipse

When I start up Eclipse, it gives me an error saying:

```
An error has occurred. See the log file
/home/Vendetta/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/configuration/1428564435095.log
```

on Linux Debian

Can you tell me what I should do?

Comment: You should view the log-file and look for errors!

Answer (score 0):

Well whenever I've run into similar problems, it usually meant that a plug in had become out of synch with my eclipse file directory.

Unfortunately I can't give you much more than a generic "make sure your workspace is safe and re-download eclipse" with the information you've given.

Comment: 1428564435095.log there is nothing in it !

Comment: Has Eclipse worked fine for you in the past and is just now acting up?

Comment: Then what I can tell you is to make sure that the version of Eclipse is catered to your version of Linux.  If this wasn't that helpful, would you like me to delete my answer to make it more likely someone else will answer?

Comment: Glad I could help, go ahead and close the question, unless you have any more issues.